# glVertexAttribPointer with normalize flag enabled

Tags: opengl

I am trying to draw a quad by doing the following:

`glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, GL_TRUE, 0, 0x0D4C7488);` //where 0x0D4C7488 is the address of the data passed and the data being (from the Visual Studio memory window):

0x0D4C7488  3699537464  875578074
0x0D4C7490  4253028175  875578074
0x0D4C7498  3699537464 2966829591
0x0D4C74A0  3699537464 2966829591
0x0D4C74A8  4253028175  875578074
0x0D4C74B0  4253028175 2966829591

```
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
```

However I don't see any quad being drawn. Also what happens with the data when the normalize flag is enabled. Help me understand what happens to the data when it is normalized and why am I not seeing any quad being drawn.

Comment: you are of course aware that this address can change?

Comment: "*Also what happens with the data when the normalize flag is enabled.*" If you don't know what it means... *why are you using it?*

Answer (score 1):

Sending a static address you've divined from a debugger or other tool is a red flag. What you *should* be doing is setting an offset into the buffer that contains your vertex data. If you have just position vectors, this should be 0. Read into OpenGL's [vertex specification](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Vertex_Specification) for a good understanding of how to do this (it's better than the somewhat cryptic spec pages). Depending on whether you interleave attributes (such as normals and tex coords) this can change.

To answer your question about normalization, it basically has to deal with converting integers to floats and you can also read that in OpenGL's [vertex specification](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Vertex_Specification) as well. If you're already using float, set it to false.

Comment: I am not sending a static address, this is just demonstration purpose.

Comment: @user1128265 What are you trying to demonstrate? You're sending the function a garbage constant.